# Android Studio: Share to Facebook Messenger

Tags: android, facebook, share

I am using the newest facebook SDK, and I am trying to share an image that i have on my device. I have tried everything and now I do not know what to do, but turn to you for help. Here is the code:

```
        String mimeType = "image/gif";


  Uri contentUri = Uri.parse("/storage/emulated/0/animated.gif");
  // contentUri points to the content being shared to Messenger
        ShareToMessengerParams shareToMessengerParams =
                ShareToMessengerParams.newBuilder(contentUri, mimeType)
                        .build();

// Sharing from an Activity
        MessengerUtils.shareToMessenger(
                this,
                1,
                shareToMessengerParams);
```

So this gives me this error (from my LogCat):

```
icky.messengersayit E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.inc.nicky.messengersayit, PID: 27783
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3969)




FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.inc.nicky.messengersayit, PID: 13162
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3969)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4637)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19422)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5586)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3964)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4637)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19422)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5586)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported URI scheme: null
        at com.facebook.messenger.ShareToMessengerParams.<init>(ShareToMessengerParams.java:106)
        at com.facebook.messenger.ShareToMessengerParamsBuilder.build(ShareToMessengerParamsBuilder.java:120)
        at com.inc.nicky.messengersayit.PersonalSettings.shareFile(PersonalSettings.java:193)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3964)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4637)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19422)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5586)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: `Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag.`

Answer (score 0):

After you updated your logcat I´d guess that this are the important lines:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported URI scheme: null
        at com.facebook.messenger.ShareToMessengerParams.<init>(ShareToMessengerParams.java:106)
        at com.facebook.messenger.ShareToMessengerParamsBuilder.build(ShareToMessengerParamsBuilder.java:120)
```

This is caused because you`re not providing a fully qualified URI. Following the facebook sdk:

> The uri of the local content. Must be a file://, content://, or res:// URI.

Comment: I do not start a new intent.

Comment: @EnderNicky according to facebook api: **shareToMessenger(Activity, int, ShareToMessengerParams)**

_Starts an intent to share a piece of media on Messenger using the messenger content platform._

Comment: on my phone it just says: sorry, activity Messenger has stopped. Send crash report?

Comment: do you call your codelines from the outside of an activity?

Comment: I updated the logcat, because the other one just seemed wrong.

Yep I might have copied the previous logcat by accident. I am terribly sorry